# PCB trace / clearance sizes (why so big?)

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I started a new job at a place that runs really high volumes using IPC class2. Before I always did lower volume at class3, so I have uncertainty here and there.

All of the boards at the new place seem to use 0.2mm (8 mil) tracks with 0.15mm (6 mil) spacing.  These traces are low current and do not have controlled impedance.

This seems huge since I am used to trace/space of 0.127mm (5mil).  Most fab houses go down to 5 mil easily - so having 8 mil traces is 60% larger than the minimum for standard boards with no cost adder.

Do boards somehow get cheaper with bigger traces?  Or more reliable?

The one last note I would make is that the large traces do seem to come at the expense of signal integrity.  On these boards there are slots in the ground planes because there is simply no room (no room with traces this large).

Thank you!

-------Edit-------

I looked further into cost of PCB vs trace width.  In general I think thicker than 5 mil doesnt save money.  Details below:

Many sites that just say trace width impacts cost but don’t go into detail.

Trace widths narrower than 5 mils (cost more)
https://www.sfcircuits.com/pcb-school/pcb-trace-widths

From a cost optimization standpoint, your traces and spaces should be greater than 4.25 mils.
https://www.protoexpress.com/pcb-cost-optimization/

Use a minimum track width / track spacing of 8/8 mil
https://camptechii.com/5-ways-to-lower-your-pcb-fabrication-cost/

Standard is 4mil/4mil (0.102mm) Trace width/spacing on 1/2oz material. https://pcbboardassembly.com/factors-that-increase-pcb-cost/

Enlarged trace widths will surely cost more; enlarged trace widths demand extra solder mask to the trails.
https://www.pcbbuy.com/news/PCB-manufacturing-cost-breakdown.html

Comment: Why don't you ask your boss? Have you looked at the signal voltage and what it needs? Is it higher than what you used previously?

Comment: Maybe it is simply because, “We’ve always done it this way. It works so why change?”

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the moment is that maybe 5 mil of trace width and spacing is outside the capabilities of the PCB manufacturer(s) that your company works with, so it could be way cheaper than any other manufacturer. Sometimes this could be a technical limitation for the designers. Of course, as Andy said, the best way is to ask your managers/directors. I remember once I was told that we shouldn't use lower than 0.4mm dia-vias for our designs unless there was no other way, otherwise we had to work with other "relatively more expensive" manufacturers.

Comment: There's not a whole lot that can be determined from a design just by looking at the board, having familiarity with manufacturing rules, and some signal quality or EMC rules of thumb, without also being intimately familiar with the components used on the board, the signals they produce and exchange, how the board is placed within its assembly, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and insight to this.  I think the thick traces are sort of a result of always having done it this way (and maybe from getting burnt on a thin trace that took more current than initially thought).

On thing I will try is reaching out to fabricators that I have used and asking if going with thicker traces is cheaper than simply going with the minimum trace size on the standard menu. 

From reading on the internet it seems that a fabricator is going to do a great job of producing things off of the standard menue (and electrical test covers the rest).  

Thanks!

Comment: I looked into PCB cost vs trace width.  In general I think anything above 5 mil doesnt save money.  Some links below:
Many sites that just say trace width impacts cost but don’t go into detail.
Trace widths narrower than 5 mils (cost more)
https://www.sfcircuits.com/pcb-school/pcb-trace-widths 

From a cost optimization standpoint, your traces and spaces should be greater than 4.25 mils.
https://www.protoexpress.com/pcb-cost-optimization/

Standard is 4mil/4mil (0.102mm) Trace width/spacing on 1/2oz material. https://pcbboardassembly.com/factors-that-increase-pcb-cost/

Comment: You won't find much of importance, or more than general points, from short blurbs and articles. Sending real designs for quote is where stuff happens. But mind that proto prices don't mean much either; numbers start to get serious for PCBs in the 1000s quantity. And you will want to quote between proto, domestic and foreign services at those kinds of quantities; and you might not make business decisions by material cost alone, but take leadtime and quality into consideration as well. Trace width is *way* down in the noise at this point.